# How many Android notifications are you allowed to make?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am currently trying to test out my code to make sure that notification are being set correctly. The way I am doing it is by setting 3 different Alarms that show a notifications a minute apart. But the problem is, 1 works, but I never see the other two. My code:

---

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                    .setTicker(intent.getStringExtra("event")+"-"+intent.getStringExtra("location"))
                                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                    .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("event"))
                                    .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("time_start")+"-"+intent.getStringExtra("location"))
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    mNotificationManager.notify(intent.getIntExtra("id", 0),notification);
```

The "id" that is the extra in the intent it gets are incrementing numbers, so like 1, 2, 3. I am setting the alarms using `AlarmManager`. I thought that as long as the first argument in `notify` was unique, it would show the notifications, but it hasn't yet. Any reasons for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I remember having a problem similar to this, the answer [here][1] may help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192569/android-notification-callback

Comment: Hmm, I took a look at what you said and the Doc, it makes sense I guess!! Ima try it

Comment: Still did not work. I changed it to the way you mentioned, but my issue persists.

Comment: Where is that code sample from, a service? an activity?

Comment: Dude, I think I solved the problem! Thank to you pointing me in the right direction, I went looking for PendingIntent issues. You were definitely right. It was cacheing my intent

Comment: YES!! I definitely figured it out thanks to another post discussion on PendingIntent. Thanks @NoBugs! You lead me to the right place so just put your answer so I can accept it. It was the best attempt. I will also put how I was able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging due to NoBug's point on `PendingIntent`s not really recreating a new instance, but rather it just retrieving the last one, I figured out that it took more than just saying `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`. When using that as a parameter from either `getBroadcast()` or `getActivity()`, all it does is uses the old one and sort of refreshes it. Instead of overriding the old instance of the `Intent` it was passed, it still uses it, just changes the extras. But even then it doesn't actually do what it says for some reason, at least in my case which the goal was to make notifications pop up one after another, with mostly the same extras, minus the times of course.

So I found out that using `intent.setAction("com.example"+System.currentTimeInMillis)` gets the job done. What this does is differentiates the `Intent` completely, so when you create a new one, its actually just a different action regardless of the `PendingIntent`. I would really recommend anyone to really elaborate more on this theory of mine as it's really just a guess from trial-and-error.